# Meteor how to efficiently publish documents from a collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Documents in the `Collection` contains a field called `userId` which stores the `_id` of the user who created the document. A user may create many documents.

The `_id` of this document is stored in an array inside the users profile whcih contains all the document `_id` that they have created

As the all document `_id` fields are indexed, is there a huge difference in speed to find and publish between the following two cursors? I am asking as the collection will hold thousands of documents.

```
Collection.find({_id: {$in: {arrayOf_ids}}})
```

or

```
Collection.find({'userId': this.userId})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's back up a tick...
If 1 user has many docs, and each doc has 1 user, why are you storing it in 2 places? You're doubling your writes to the DB & opening yourself up to inconsistencies. Just store the `userId` on the doc, index that field, & be done with it.

To answer your question:
The first won't really use an index because you're essentially passing in an array that mongo has to iterate through to see if 1 of the values matches the id.
If your `_id` were 3, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.indexOf(3);
```

You can verify that by calling `.explain()` and see how many docs it touches, the index it uses, & the time it takes.

Thankfully, none of it really matters until you get to the hundreds of thousands, but good job planning ahead!

Comment: One user has many docs, as I have explained these document ids are stored in the users profile for them to reference. Your explanation regarding how mongo will iterate over the array is helpful. Thank you Matt

Comment: right, instead of storing the ids in the users profile, subscribe to the document collection.